# Netbeans Error: Could not find or load main class (again)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am very experienced in Java, but not in Netbeans. I have a project that I've been working on, a little test program for a particular issue, so I have been making changes to it and running it and debugging it many times a day, every day, for several weeks. Yesterday Netbeans quit running it the way I had been running it, and I can't seem to get it started again.

The entire output when I run the project is:

```
run: Error: Could not find or load main class 

C:\Users\rcook\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I note for whatever it's worth that the classname does not appear on the first line, as it seems to with others who have had the "could not find" error.

This happens whether I run the project (select the project and press F6) or the file (select the file and press control-F6). I have cleaned and rebuilt the project (which I didn't do often before, I've wondered if it *caused* the problem). I have restarted Netbeans. I have restarted the (Win7) computer. I am not running any memory-hogging programs except for Outlook, which I have been running the entire time it was working.

I can run the program from the command line by setting my default directory down to the 'classes' directory under the project and entering `java stsclientexample3.STSClientExample3`.

I have checked the "Run" configuration many times -- there are no program or VM options entered, it has the correct classname. Oddly enough, if I change the classname to something that isn't there, Netbeans displays a popup that says the invalid name class wasn't found in the project, and listing the main classes available. But when I do that and select the one to run, it gives the same "could not find" error. There's one other main class in the project, if I select THAT it gives the same "could not find" error.

I have looked at the XML file referenced in the message, but it is full of ${parameter} references that I don't know the resolution of. It would likely be helpful to know how Netbeans resolves "${classname}", for instance, or even to dump the value Netbeans has at runtime somehow.

I have commented out code and re-run. Same result.

I have deleted that class from the run configuration, restarted Netbeans, and added the class back. Same result.

By now I've read more than a dozen other queries for a similar error, on SO and other places; I've tried all the things that looked at all possible (skipping things like configuring for special-purpose libraries, etc.).

Anyone know how to fix this?

---

EDIT: before someone asks, another project with a `main()` runs using the 'run project' option.

EDIT2: I forgot to mention, also, that another post recommended that one delete the Netbeans cache (c:\Users\\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache), so I shut down NetBeans, deleted everything in that directory, and restarted NetBeans. Same result.

Comment: Please be sure that your netbeans workspace won't have a lot of projects! Because at the time of loading projects into netbeans need a lot memory resources so the Heap Size could be out of memory enough to compile the bytecode!
http://stackoverflow.com/q/27636272/3411946

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind. I cleared out a bunch of projects and copied relevant code into a new one; that's solved the problem for now. My company has things organized into a bunch of projects, so I may see it again. I'm afraid it doesn't say much good about the robustness/error reporting of Netbeans...

Answer (score 7):

I've encountered this problem a few times and it is very frustrating. If you delete the cache it should fix it after you rebuild the project

1. Close netbeans
2. Delete the Cache folder `User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\` (Windows 7 and above)
3. Open Netbeans
4. Rebuild and run

Edit - you can find the cache directory also by going in netbeans to `Help - About` then it shows your cache directory.

Comment: Shoot - I forgot to mention that I had already done this. I will edit the original post. Thanks for mentioning it, but it was in one of the other posts that I read and so I tried it. No luck.

Comment: Damn, that sucks. Honestly no idea, this solution worked for me the few times i've gotten this error. You did the Clean and Build option too? (Shift F11)

Comment: Yes, did that. Thanks anyway. One thing that gets me about this is that, if one understood how Netbeans functions, i.e., how it determined its classpath, the class it is supposed to run, etc., the answer would be *trivial*, and would involve NO trial-and-error hocus-pocus stuff. And that no one appears to know that info, and that no one appears baffled, outraged, disturbed, or even puzzled that no one has that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new class with main method and copy your code into this class.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the Netbeans. Go to **C:\Users\YOUR_PC_NAME\AppData\Local\Netbeans** and delete the **Cache** folder. The open the Netbeans again and run the project. It works like magic for me.

(**AppData** folder might be hidden probably, if so, you need to make it appear in Folder Options).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in the Netbeans IDE 8,2. I had the same problem and in my `manifest.mf`, the field classpath: was empty(I noticed that because I got the message:

> java returned 1 could not load main class ExerciseFinal

I looked at the classpath nb where searching and I simply changed one folder's name and then after restarting netbeans everything worked.

My file name was "teo_1=1;" and I changed it to "teo" simply because I thought that maybe 1=1 (always true) was messing the nb.

Comment: if programm is in location with national symbol in its path then nb would throw this problem, i found it in another question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i think the problem was in the file path, either it was too long or it had some forbidden characters(now i have seen that it was a letter from my language), when i copied a project to a different folder it worked...

Answer (score 0):

After an eternity of trying to figure it out myself, looking through every menu, submenu, tab, and option, I was still stuck. Nothing anybody suggested worked for me.

How many hours did I spend flailing about in the name of pride and self-education? Several. How long did what I'm about to suggest take? Maybe 10 minutes; 15 tops.

Was my journey a waste? No. I learned a lot. But since I hadn't set out to learn what I did and was prevented from work I needed to do, I was pissed long before giving that up and copping out.

So... Long story short, do this:

(Step 1 has been deleted; renumbering steps might be bad idea. So start with 2!)

Step 2: Open the problem project.

Step 3: Create a new Netbeans project, get into Project view, and expand both projects to show their packages.

Step 4: *Thoughtfully* copy all packages from problem project to new. 
(This means to hold off on the "main" package until last to avoid a chuteload of red-marked errors. If you see a bunch anyway, don't look at them. Further copying will fix many.)

NOTE: Having to choose a different project name for the new project will likely lead to a new name for your new "main" java class file. No problem. Just note this.

Step 5: Once you've copied all but the "main" package from problem project to new, open the "main" package to see your files. Then open the new "main" package, which will have ONE tiny file in it.

Step 6: Thoughtfully copy one file at a time (holding off on the "main" class file until last) from problem project to new.

(If you see errors, let 'em go. Not finished yet.)

Step 7: Once you have only the "main" class file left to copy from the problem project, open it. Also open the new "main" class file in the new project.

Step 8: Copy all the code from problem project "main" java class file and paste it into the new project's "main" file.

Step 9. There will be errors at the end. After all, at least one package and one file name changed. So open each source file with an error, put the cursor on each line with error, and press Alt-Enter to get a hint. Renaming the new main file or changing some old package names to new will fix a few, especially in some imports; this might just get rid of the rest.

I hope this helps someone. I should look for a more recent post and put this Answer there, if it gets enough upvotes.

Comment: Interesting, but given that there are many distinct causes and solutions for this error, I am not understanding your comment _"Don't waste your time with bogus suggestions..."_. Suggestions are not _"bogus"_ if they worked for someone else, and it is unavoidable to "waste your time" with those suggestions that happen not to work for you personally. You have to try them to see whether they work, right? Or am I completely misunderstanding your point?

Comment: @skomisa--Yes, you're right about my comment about "bogus suggestions". Go ahead and try them. My point was, though, that my method is pretty easy to apply and won't take as long as the usual suggestions (I guess these are the "bogus" ones) of exiting and restarting or reinstalling Netbeans or rebooting or some combination of those. But the fact is, who knows if my method will work for everyone. But given that Netbeans is stable, why wouldn't it work? In any event, I've edited out the "bogus" comment. Good point.